# Run a directive after the DOM has finished rendering Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have API that return data to me, when the DOM rendered at first time the data is empty for few seconds, then it contains information, how can I delay the ngIf so that the image will not appear for few second.

```
<div *ngIf="data == ''">
    <img [src]="appUrl + 'assets/img/no_data/no_text.png'">
</div>
```

Comment: What is `data`? Is it initialized to an empty string? If so what you have should work. You should avoid coercive comparisons however.

Comment: `@Input() public data: any = [];` this is my data

Comment: Obviously that's not an empty string. Also your type annotation is actually reducing the quality of your code. Remove it at once

Comment: I tried to make it    ` @Input() public data: any = '';` but nothing changed

Comment: `@Input() data = []` and `*ngIf="data.length"`

Comment: Remove the `any`. It's completely rediculous that you are writing more code so that it can be of lower quality. Do you think type annotations are required or something insane like that?

Comment: I remove it, `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: So you removed the initializer as well? Why?

Comment: Dear, all I want that the data before API is empty, after response is not, I want the ngIf run after the response comes. Thank you